# Increasing compression in animations over time?

Tags: rendering, animation

iMac High Sierra

I've tried a few different containers (some fail) and
a few different quality settings and the animations always
look worse frame by frame.

Frames look fine when rendered alone.[image: I know, not the best image.]

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure what your problem is, are you having problems with your rendered videos looking low res when you view them from a video player?

Comment: It's always better to render frame by frame and then to use the video editor to stitch them together. It often gets corrupted if you try to render the animation as a video straight from the viewport.

Comment: Thanks.
Never had this problem before 2.8.